# Enable color regex debugging in perl on windows

Tags: regex, windows, perl, debugging

In some of my perl scripts, I've found it necessary to enable regex debugging while I work on them. I've seen that there is a color mode, but I can't seem to get color output. I've added `use re 'debugcolor';` to my program, but it seems to behave no different than `use re 'debug';`.

I'm wondering if cmd.exe doesn't support the color output. Any [documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/lib/pods/perlretut.html#pragmas_and_debugging) I've found just says that it will work on a terminal that supports it.

My question boils down to: Is there something else I need to do to enable color output? or, alternatively, What other terminal program could I use instead of cmd.exe?

Comment: This may be relevant... [answers.yahoo](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070402210230AA8VFEy)

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe http://www.cygwin.com/ is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[re](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re) uses unix's `termcap` to provide color information. Try:

```
BEGIN {
   require Win32::Console::ANSI;
   $ENV{PERL_RE_COLORS} = "\e[1m\t\e[0m\t\e[7m\t\e[27m\t\e[4m\t\e[24m";
}
```

I get some colors from that. I don't know if they're the ones you are expecting.

Comment: Of course, this is a workaround. If you want something better, it'll have to be done inside of re.pm. You can file a bug report using the `perlbug` tool.